# TimeStamps with milliseconds in XmlRpc Requests / Response from/to Odoo/OpenErp

Tags: java, timestamp, odoo, xml-rpc

I want to read objects from OpenERP / Odoo with the XMLRPC interface. When I'm debugging the response I'll see, that all of the timestamps doesn't have a milliseconds part.

Is it possible to change OpenErp/Odoo settings so I'll get the milliseconds?

Answer (score 1):

ODOO Server use `DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT` and `DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT` for formating the  date and date time

> My Answer is Yes you can modify the  `DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT` and
>   `DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT`.

For this just update these value in [openerp/tools/misc.py](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/openerp/tools/misc.py#L670)

I hope this may help in solving your issue .

Comment: Thank you! But, when I'm changing this, all the timestamps displayed in the frontend will have the milliseconds too. That would be confusing to some users. ;)

Comment: hi @ Mirko, from my understanding  this is the solution Which i  have fond so far  , yes it true that it will affect the front-ends/website   .if you tell me what you are actually trying to do or i say trying to developed then it's may possible that i can help in developing that thing